# UISearchController searchbar disappear after clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have `UISearchController` in my application:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
[self.searchController setSearchResultsUpdater:self];
[self.searchController setDelegate:self];

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.1")) {
    self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
}

self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

[self.searchBarView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

The issue is that after i click the search bar it disappears from the screen:
[image]
[image]

Any idea how i can fix this problem?

Comment: instead of manually adding a subview.. try `navigationItem.searchController = searchController`

Answer (score 0):

add these line of code in your `controller`

```
 self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
 self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
 self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

hope it will solve your issue ... if not ... let me know in comments

Comment: I tried it but when i use it the searchvc not fill the screen after clicked

Comment: try it out now .